# Execute bash command after a specified string is contained in output

Tags: bash, while-loop

I'm trying to run this command:

```
~ $ sudo ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i funnyVideo.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

which every second outputs the frame number it's displaying:

```
... other ...
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=N/A speed=0.0665x
```

then the last line is replaced with the new displayed frame number.

```
frame=   23 fps= 23 q=-0.0 size=N/A time=00:00:00.76 bitrate=N/A dup=15 drop=0
```

and so on. I'm trying to wait for the string "frame=   205", execute another script and let the process continue:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    if [[ "$line" =~ "frame=   205" ]]; then
          echo "Frame 205 has been reached"
          break;
    fi
done < <(sudo ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -re -i funnyVideo.mp4 -map 0:v -f v4l2 /dev/video2)
```

I have no idea what's going on here. Why isn't it `echo`ing `Frame 205 has been reached` even if I can see the line containing text `frame=  205` after a while?

Comment: Try `[[ "$l" =~ ^frame=[[:space:]]+200[[:space:]] ]]`. Also, add `echo "$line"` to the loop to verify you're getting the output you expect from ffmpeg. Alternatively: `while read -r x n line; do if [[ "$n" -eq 200 ]]; then ...`.

Comment: Given the answer below, you could do `while read -r x n line; do if ((n >= 200 )); then ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you can see it is the problem. You never output the lines you read, so how are they showing up? It's because they're not captured.

To capture such lines, redirect stderr to stdout with `<(sudo ffmpeg ... 2>&1)`

You will then find that `ffmpeg` doesn't output `\n`s between these updates, which is how it's making the line update in place. You can use `IFS= read -d $'\r' -r line` to read carriage returns separators instead.

PS: The frame numbers are based on a timer and therefore not deterministic. Sometimes it'll give you `frame=  205` and sometimes `frame=  209`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Regarding the frame numbers not being deterministic, I've actually ran the command multiple times and it still gives me the same numbers.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I think you're right, they change. They're not deterministic, but how can I set it to actually print all the frames it's displaying?

Comment: As far as I know, this is not supported